# Symfony 2 - not authenticating user using bcrypt

Tags: php, symfony, bcrypt

I add a user to the database.

I encode their password using bcrypt encryption:

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(),$user->getSalt());
$postData->setPassword($password);
```

This all persists to the database just fine.

On my User Entity my getSalt() method returns null:

```
public function getSalt(){
    return null;
}
```

Now when I try to authenticate the symfony logs tells me that I am entering bad credentials.

However...

If i use this site to encrypt my password with bcrypt:

http://bcrypthashgenerator.apphb.com/

Then enter the result into the database manually and try and authenticate with the users password i have updated with the results from the above link,
It works fine.

So there is something I have not set, that when I am encrypting the password that Symfony cannot authenticate against it.

I have tried the setting a salt on the `getSalt()`, setting it to an empty string.

### Edit

I am using PHP 5.5.9

I have also tried using the BCryptPasswordEncoder($cost) class,
setting the cost on the __construct the same as what's in my `security.yml` and it still does not authenticate.

### Edit

I have also tried installing this class via composer to [as suggested here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder).

### Edit

If I use the PHP method:

```
password_hash('testertester',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array('cost'=>13));
```

It authenticates perfectly.

So it's something to do deeper in Symfony. I'll keep digging.

Still no luck. I am scouring the web to no avail so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing in the existing entity object not the submitted data object!!

```
$postData = $form->getdata();

$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);

$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(),$user->getSalt());

$postData->setPassword($password);
```

Note this line here:

$user->getPassword() needed to be $postData->getPassword()

```
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($postData->getPassword(),$user->getSalt());
```

You live and learn ay!